# Use discount code field for Gift Certificate redemption in Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, giftcertificates

I've heard there is a way to use the discount code field of a checkout form to accept gift certificate codes within Cartthrob.

Despite Googling I can't find any reference to this. Does anyone know if this is possible or does the gift certificate redemption require its own form?

This makes it difficult to use in the checkout as that is itself a form. Forms in forms are bad! I know this could be done with Ajax but it seems silly to have to do that when a simple field on the checkout form will do.

Comment: Do you recall where you read that? Is it possible the person was using an extension on one of the CT hooks?

Comment: I was told it by someone else who said they had read it. So very third-hand information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a supported feature that I'm aware of. The [documentation for the gift certificate addon is here](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/docs_gift-certificates/) and specifically mentions [using the dedicated form](https://www.cartthrob.com//docs/docs_gift-certificates/#redeeming-gift-certificates). I think it's best to use that method.